# AWS ECS custom CloudWatch metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs, statsd

I'm looking for a way to establish custom metrics over StatsD protocol for Amazon Elastic Container Service. I've found a documentation on how to [establish Amazon CloudWatch Agent on EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html). It works well. However I'm failing to find a correct configuration for Dockerfile. Quite probably some set of custom IAM permissions will also be required there.

*Is it possible to have Docker containers working from AWS ECS with custom metrics using StatsD reporting to AWS CloudWatch?*

Answer (score 0):

Rather than building your own container, you can use the one provided by Amazon. [This article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/deploy-container-insights-ECS-instancelevel.html) explains how, including a link to an [example daemon service task configuration](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudwatch-container-insights/latest/ecs-task-definition-templates/deployment-mode/daemon-service/cwagent-ecs-instance-metric/cwagent-ecs-instance-metric.json).